# Calling func session didReceiveMessage in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, watchos-2, watchconnectivity, wcsession

The user can already tweet (the text that was dictated on watch) in foreground if a specific vc is active on the iPhone.

But now I want to go a step forward and send this tweet **in Background**. So the user dictate a text in the watch app and the text is tweeting even if the app on the iPhone is closed.

I have used this code for the definitions:

```
let accountStore = ACAccountStore()
let accountType = ACAccountStore().accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter)
var twitterAccount: ACAccount?
var session: WCSession!
```

And that for the method:

```
func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject]) {
    let message2Tweet = message["text2Tweet"]! as? String

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "CalledAppDelegate")
        print("Nachricht in AppDelegate: \(message2Tweet)")


        if(WCSession.isSupported()){
            self.session = WCSession.defaultSession()
            self.session.delegate = self
            self.session.activateSession()
        }

        self.accountStore.requestAccessToAccountsWithType(self.accountType, options: nil) { (success, error) -> Void in
            if !success {

                print("Kein Zugriff")

            } else {

                let allAccounts = self.accountStore.accountsWithAccountType(self.accountType)

                if allAccounts.count > 0 {
                    self.twitterAccount = allAccounts.last as? ACAccount
                }
            }

            let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json")

            let txt = message2Tweet

            if txt != "" {
                let request = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter, requestMethod: .POST, URL: url, parameters: ["status": txt!])
                request.account = self.twitterAccount

                request.performRequestWithHandler { (data, response, error) -> Void in

                    if response.statusCode != 200 {

                        print(error)
                    } else {

                        print("No error")
                    }


                }

            }



        }

    })

}
```

But it's not working in the for- and background.

How to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `iPhone` app is closed and you have implemented the

```
 func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject]) {
}
```

in a  specific VC you won't get the message until your VC is live but if you have implemented the above method in `AppDelegate` , you will received it even when your app is closed.

As mentioned in the [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/WatchConnectivity/Reference/WCSession_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WCSession/sendMessage:replyHandler:errorHandler:)

> Calling this method from your WatchKit extension while it is active
>   and running wakes up the corresponding iOS app in the background and
>   makes it reachable. Calling this method from your iOS app does not
>   wake up the corresponding WatchKit extension

Your app did wake up in background but since your VC is not live that's why you are not getting the message.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I already had used this in the AppDelegate. But's it's bot working one More Time. That's why I thought that it's not right to simply use this in the AppDelegate. To get sure a that there is no other reason I set a bool NSUserDefault to true if the AppDelegate get a message and checked that in my app with a print in the console. And it's still false, so there was no message.

Comment: Thats strange! i have tried this and its working.Can you show the implementation of didReceiveMessage?

Comment: ` func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject]) {
        let message2Tweet = message["text2Tweet"]! as? String
    
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            \\Whole code is too long...
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "CalledAppDelegate")
            print("Nachricht in AppDelegate: \(message2Tweet)")     

    }
 `

Comment: Why are you activating the WCSession in your didReceiveMessage function. The session needs to be activated prior to that. Put the WCSession  activiation code in didFinishLaunchWithOptions of AppDelegate.

Comment: Thank you! That solves! But why should I call this in didFinishLaunchWithOptions, I thought this method is only activating if I launch the App...

Comment: No if you are class is supposed to interact with WCSession then the session must be activated as soon as that class is lived so that it will listen/receive the message,. In case of UIViewController  write the activiation code in viewDidLoad and since in AppDelegate the didfinishlaunchWithOptions is the first method so we write the code there